# Emacs suspends right after starting in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, emacs

(Possibly) important info:
Ubuntu version - 16.04 LTS
GNU Emacs version - 24.5.1
GNU bash version - 4.3.42(1)-release

I'm trying to edit my apache2.conf file in `/etc/apache2/`, but using

```
sudo emacs -mm apache2.conf &
```

to start Emacs doesn't work. In particular, it doesn't ask me for the root password, and the process just suspends immediately after starting. `bg` doesn't work either because the process just suspends again.

**edit**:
When starting Emacs as a foreground process instead, I'm asked for the root password, and the process doesn't suspend.

What might be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because sudo meanwhile not works for many GUI based applications, use `gksudo` instead which you will find in the package `gksu`. So example:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
gksudo emacs -mm apache2.conf &
```

Happy hacking.